# MongoDB get value of an Array

Tags: mongodb, charts, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a data like this.

```
"name": "Roboert Browning",
"delivery": [{
        "status": "Not Started",
        "createdAt": "$date": "2020-12-21T03:50:33.877Z",
        "updatedAt": "$date": "2020-12-21T03:50:33.877Z"
    }, {
        "status": "Accepted",
        "updatedAt": "$date": "2020-12-21T03:51:20.915Z",
        "createdAt": "$date": "2020-12-21T03:51:20.915Z"
    }],
"price": 500,
```

How can I get the value of *delivery* *status*: "Not Started" and *delivery* *status*: "Accepted"

Example Output:

```
"createdAt": "2020-12-21T03:50:33.877Z" // from the status: "Not Started"
```

and

```
"createdAt": "2020-12-21T03:51:20.915Z" // from the status: "Accepted"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to solve the problem.

```
    db.deliveryStatus.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$delivery"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "delivery.status": "Not Started"
        },
        {
          "delivery.status": "Accepted"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      createdAt: "$delivery.createdAt",
      status: "$delivery.status",
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Play with the live example here - https://mongoplayground.net/p/4wexjbi0s31